# Having trouble getting values to sum up in a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I'm creating a pre-process script that will read in a csv file, look at two fields (P_ID and don_date), concatenate the two together to create a key for my hash entry, and then keep the line (split into an array) as my value for the key.

If another line in the file has the same p_id and don_date (which will match my catted hash key), I want to take the other values you see in the code and add them to the values of the existing hash entry.  I'm doing some testing, but I'm a little confused as to how referencing/de-referencing and all that works in Perl (I'm a Python guy), so that each line will have a unique P_ID/Don_Date value, or else it will be rolled up into an existing one.

```
my @lineFields = ();
my %rollUpHash = ();

# Open file and loop through lines
#foreach my $line (<INFH>)
while(my $line = <INFH>)
  {
      # chomp($line);
      # print STDERR "New line in file\n";
      # <STDIN>;
      @lineFields = split(/,/, $line);

      # Pull out pertinent values for possible roll-up into a total
      my $p_id = $lineFields[18];
      my $don_date = $lineFields[19];
      my $nd_amt = $lineFields[14];
      my $deduct_amt = $lineFields[15];
      my $nondeduct_ytd = $lineFields[16];
      my $deduct_ytd = $lineFields[17];
      my $amount = $lineFields[24];
      my $anonymous = $lineFields[26];
      my $int_code_ex0003 = $lineFields[39];
      my $int_code_ex0006 = $lineFields[40];
      my $int_code_ex0028 = $lineFields[41];
      my $sumDeduct_NonDeduct_ytd = $deduct_ytd + $nondeduct_ytd;
      my $hashKey = $p_id . $don_date;
      # say "P_ID is $p_id\nDon_Date is $don_date\nND_Amt is $nd_amt\nDeduct_Amt is $deduct_amt\nNonDeduct_YTD is $nondeduct_ytd\nDeduct_YTD is $deduct_ytd\nAmount is $amount\nAnonymous is $anonymous\n0003 is $int_code_ex0003\n0006 is $int_code_ex0006\n0028 is $int_code_ex0028";
      # say "hashKey is $hashKey";
      # say "$sumDeduct_NonDeduct_ytd";

      if (exists($rollUpHash{$hashKey}))
        {
          say("Same key found, summing up!")
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[14] += $lineFields[14];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[15] += $lineFields[15];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[16] += $lineFields[16];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[17] += $lineFields[17];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[24] += $lineFields[24];
          push @{$rollUpHash{$hashKey}}, $sumDeduct_NonDeduct_ytd;
          # print %rollUpHash;
        }
      else
        {
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey} = \@lineFields;
        }
        foreach my $key (keys %rollUpHash)
        {
            print OUTFH "$key is @{$rollUpHash{$key}}";
        }
```

Here are three lines of scrubbed input data:

```
152099-00001,,100,100,400,100,175,100,700,200,200,500,0,0,0,300,0,2575,105666,10/28/14,197800,23764962,"Jefferson,Mark",300,1004,N,N,N,D,Mike and Bonnie,Mike and Bonnie Gregorovitch,715 81st St NE,,,Central,IL,52402-7256,UNITED STATES,,,,,Y,soandso@email.com,,(888) 888-8888,"Jefferson,Mark",2222B,BASIC,,
342029-00015,,200,0,400,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,0,0,0,200,0,2000,3184444,09/27/14,197800,40949,"Macrow,Gregory",100,1004,N,N,N,D,John and Amber, John and Amber Meadows,PO Box 706,,,Logan,MD,01111-0704,UNITED STATES,,,,,Y,othersoandso@email,,(999) 999-9999,"Macrow,Gregory",2222B,BASIC,,
342029-00014,,200,0,400,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,0,0,0,200,0,2000,3184444,09/27/14,197800,22145,"Bartholomew,Vincent",100,1004,N,N,N,D,John and Amber, John and Amber Meadows,PO Box 706,,,Logan,MD,01111-0704,UNITED STATES,,,,,Y,othersoandso@email,,(999) 999-9999,"Bartholomew,Vincent",2222B,BASIC,,
```

Any help sorting this problem out would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem/question? Can you show 3 lines of input?

Comment: The only thing odd I see is `push @{$rollUpHash{$hashKey}}, $sumDeduct_NonDeduct_ytd;`

Comment: @choroba it has been added to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do with the `$sumDeduct_NonDeduct_ytd`: do you really want to append new sums to the line, or just replace the last column with it?

Also, using `split /,/` on CSV that contains quoted commas is wrong. Use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Text::CSV;

use constant {
    ND_AMT        => 14,
    DEDUCT_AMT    => 15,
    NONDEDUCT_YTD => 16,
    DEDUCT_YTD    => 17,
    PID           => 18,
    DON_DATE      => 19,
    AMOUNT        => 24,
};


my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary => 1 });

my %hash;
open my $IN, '<:encoding(utf-8)', shift or die $!;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($IN)) {
    my $key = join ':', @{$row}[PID, DON_DATE];
    if (exists $hash{$key}) {
        $hash{$key}[$_] += $row->[$_] for ND_AMT, DEDUCT_AMT, NONDEDUCT_YTD,
                                          DEDUCT_YTD, AMOUNT;
        my $sum = $row->[DEDUCT_YTD] + $row->[NONDEDUCT_YTD];
        $hash{$key}[-1] = $sum;      # Or do you mean something else?
    } else {
        $hash{$key} = $row;          # You can store the reference directly,
    }                                # as you get a fresh new one for each iteration.
}

for my $key (keys %hash) {
    say "$key : @{ $hash{$key} }";   # You should rather use $csv->print.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips!! I will be walking through these to try and understand them a little better.

Comment: Thank you sir, this did exactly what I wanted.  Now I just need to walk through the TEXT::CSV module to understand all the syntax!:)

Answer (score 1):

You are storing a pointer to variable `@lineFields` inside to the `rollUpHash` hash, but it is the same variable. So you end up with hash which all values are the pointer to the same one array which content you repeatedly destroy and fill with some other content. It doesn't make sense. You have to move `my @lineFields` inside the `while` cycle or change line

```
$rollUpHash{$hashKey} = \@lineFields;
```

into

```
$rollUpHash{$hashKey} = [@lineFields];
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  Do the [] around my array make a copy of it?

Comment: Yep, exactly. You can think about it as `[@a]` is an equivalent of `do { my @b = @a; \@b }` where `=` copy the content of the array. But I personally would prefer moving variable declaration inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems with this:

First address issues when the keys does not repeat

1. Your foreach print statement is in while loop.

I printed the output and it is weird. 
3 lines of input gives 4 lines of output (add more new lines to see that)

I will help fixing other issues as updates